# Is there anything wrong?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning python Selenium and I have created a list of 'email':'password'. I need to insert those emails in the right place, then the passwords, and then the login button. This is the code:

```
f = open('users.txt','r')
for line in f.readlines():
    print(line)
    mail = line[0:line.index(':')]
    line = line[line.index(':')+1:]
    password = line
    email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
    email_input.click()
    email_input.send_keys(mail)
    password_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
    password_input.click()
    password_input.send_keys(password)
    lgn_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sign-in')
    lgn_btn.click()
    n_url = driver.current_url
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.refresh()
```

And the error I get is:

> mail = line[0:line.index(':')]
> ValueError: substring not found

the txt file is:

```
g_santeusanio@arcor.de:sportpark13 
mrtslabbert@absamail.co.za:oohethooq12313w 
lauriecd@absamail.co.za:christcorem
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If there weren't anything wrong, would you be posting this? That is not an adequate title for a post. What type of search arguments do you think it would satisfy?

Comment: Does the text file have blank lines in between the email addresses, as you have shown here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
line.find(':')
```

instead of `line.index(':')`
This is because, the index() method searches for a substring in the and returns it's index.

Since you want to find a single character in a string, you should use the `find()` method!

Text file used for both codes, demo :

[image]

**Edit based on @John Gordon 's comment**

The `index()` method returns a *Value Error* when there is no such value present in the string. The text file used has 2 empty lines. The `find()` method return a -*1* instead of an error.

Notice that the first pair of mail and password get's printed for the code block used in the question

[image]

When it searches for the value in the second line(which is empty) it raises the `ValueError`. On the other hand, if you see the output(img attached below) when using the `find()` method, it just prints out empty string and moves on!

Hence it's better to use `find()` when you are not sure if the value you want to search for is in the string or not.

**Edits based on comments from @Chris**

This is the code I used :

```
for line in f.readlines():
    # print(line)
    mail = line[0:line.find(':')]
    password = line[line.find(':') + 1:]
    print(mail)
    print(password)
```

The output I received for the text you pasted was this :

[image]

Comment: Code blocks need to be indented _or_ fenced with three backticks, not both. I have removed some extraneous backticks from your code block.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Strings have both `.index()` and `.find()` methods, and they are identical except for their behavior when the target string is not found.  I don't see how this answer addresses the real issue, which is that `:` was not found in the line.

Comment: Well the problem is not the function, but what it returns when there's no such value present in the string or if the string is empty(as in this case) `find()` returns `-1` and `index()` returns `ValueError` ! As I've said, when searching for a single character, it's always better to use the `find()` method rather than `index()` and that's my opinion . I should've mentioned about the return, will edit it now. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case [`split()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) is easier to understand and use. `split()` splits a string by a provided character and returns an array of values containing the results. In this case, we can split by ":" and get both parts.

So the first few lines become

```
for line in f.readlines():
    print(line)
    data = line.split(':')
    mail = data[0]
    password = data[1]
    ...
```

That should solve the issue you've asked about but looking on at the rest of your code, there are going to be other issues that come up and I have some suggestions.

1. Don't overwrite variables.

   ```
   line = line[line.index(':')+1:]
   ```

   It makes your code harder to follow, e.g. you overwrote `line` here with another value. Now you no longer have access to the original value of `line` and other readers (including yourself) will have a harder time debugging the code as the script gets longer and longer. Instead give it a new name to best represent what the variable will hold. In this case `password`, as you did on the next line.

   ```
   line = line[line.index(':')+1:]
   password = line
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   password = line[line.index(':')+1:]
   ```
2. Use the simplest form of a locator, e.g. if you are locating an element by ID then use `.find_element_by_id()`, not XPath or CSS selector. It will make your code easier to read.

   ```
    email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
   ```

   becomes

   ```
    email_input = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
   ```
3. You are clicking and then sending keys to elements to the same element. In general, this is not necessary and you can omit the click. (There are some cases where this IS necessary but in my experience those are fairly rare).

   ```
    email_input = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
    email_input.click()
    email_input.send_keys(mail)
   ```

   becomes

   ```
    email_input = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
    email_input.send_keys(mail)
   ```

   or even

   ```
    driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(mail)
   ```

   since it looks like you don't use `email_input` afterwards.

So to update the code with the suggestions above, it will look like this

```
for line in f.readlines():
    print(line)
    data = line.split(":")
    email = data[0]
    password = data[1]
    driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id('sign-in').click()
    n_url = driver.current_url
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.refresh()
```